# Using break for nested for loop

Tags: python, for-loop, break

I want to apply three levels of filtering on `record`.

1. `rec` in cname. `rec` is string of >2 words, so I want to consider all ngram of `rec` to be checked in `record`

   i. if `gram` matches into `record` increment `filter_company_level` and write it to file
2. 2nd Filter on record is for each value `value` in `self.keyword_material_info` list.

   i. if `value` matches into `record` increment `filter_with_material_info` and write it to file
3. 3rd filter is for `item` in `self.keyword_bse_list` .

   i. if `item` matches into `record` increment `filter_with_keyword_info` and write it to file

   ii. Now move to next record if inner most filter is present.

I have written these code, does it satisfy above conditions, or is there any bug? None of them give error but want to make sure that logic is correct.

```
        for record in fetch_record:
            total += 1
            for rec in cname:
                try:
                    c_ngram = self.get_ngrams(rec['company_name'])
                    for gram in c_ngram:
                        if gram.lower()+' ' in u'{} {}'.format(record['title'], record['description']).lower():
                            filter_company_level += 1
                            # print "Matched based on company name : ", record['article_link']
                            company_write.write(record['article_link']+' - '+rec['company_name']+' - '+rec['company_code']+'\n')
                            for value in self.keyword_material_info:
                                if value.lower()+' ' in u'{} {}'.format(record['title'], record['description']).lower():
                                    filter_with_material_info += 1
                                    materialinfo_write.write(record['article_link']+' - '+rec['company_name']+' - '+rec['company_code']+' - '+value+'\n')
                                    for item in self.keyword_bse_list:
                                        if item.lower()+' ' in u'{} {}'.format(record['title'], record['description']).lower():
                                            filter_with_keyword_info += 1
                                            keyword_write.write(record['article_link']+' - '+rec['company_name']+' - '+rec['company_code']+" - "+value+' - '+item+'\n')
                                            print record['article_link']
                                            print value
                                            print item
                                            break
                                    break
                            # break
                            raise GetOutOfLoop
                except GetOutOfLoop:
                    break
```

Or this one is correct?

```
        for record in fetch_record:
            total += 1
            for rec in cname:
                try:
                    c_ngram = self.get_ngrams(rec['company_name'])
                    for gram in c_ngram:
                        if gram.lower()+' ' in u'{} {}'.format(record['title'], record['description']).lower():
                            filter_company_level += 1
                            # print "Matched based on company name : ", record['article_link']
                            company_write.write(record['article_link']+' - '+rec['company_name']+' - '+rec['company_code']+'\n')
                            for value in self.keyword_material_info:
                                if value.lower()+' ' in u'{} {}'.format(record['title'], record['description']).lower():
                                    filter_with_material_info += 1
                                    materialinfo_write.write(record['article_link']+' - '+rec['company_name']+' - '+rec['company_code']+' - '+value+'\n')
                                    flag_keyword = 0
                                    for item in self.keyword_bse_list:
                                        if item.lower()+' ' in u'{} {}'.format(record['title'], record['description']).lower():
                                            filter_with_keyword_info += 1
                                            keyword_write.write(record['article_link']+' - '+rec['company_name']+' - '+rec['company_code']+" - "+value+' - '+item+'\n')
                                            print record['article_link']
                                            print value
                                            print item
                                            flag_keyword = 1
                                            break
                                    if flag_keyword == 1:
                                        break
                            # break
                            if flag_keyword == 1:
                                raise GetOutOfLoop
                except GetOutOfLoop:
                    break
```

Comment: Is your question essentially "test my code"?

Comment: @bereal: it is to verify my code. I dont think this question deserve downvote, as I already have clearly mentioned what I am doing and my tries. And just to remind you, SO is for coding help only.

Comment: [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) is more appropriate place for this kind of requests.

Comment: @bereal: thanks for this link, well I would like to know the reason for downvote, if you have applied

Comment: The reason is that the question is off-topic for SO because does not address any particular problem that you may have encountered and won't be useful for anyone later.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this isn't a testing service

Comment: @jonrsharpe: okay, can be closed. But FYI on SO there are 35350 tags regading unit testing and 20872 for testing. Well I still believe my code was to verify if any logical error, not for asking the people to test it on their system and let me know what is the answer. Thanks, let's close it now.

Comment: *"verify if any logical error"* - that's what testing is for. Questions with those tags are generally people who have had specific programming issues *while writing tests*.

Answer (score 2):

> I have written these code, does it satisfy above conditions, or is there any bug? None of them give error but want to make sure that logic is correct.

The best way to make sure is to write unit tests that will compare your code's outputs for the expected outputs for a given set of inputs.

Comment: thanks for this, is there any tool or package for unit test, or I should take sample data and check it?

Comment: If you want some serious automated testing, the stdlib's `unittest` package (https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html) is probably what you're looking for. You'll have to refactor your script to make it testable (have you function return values instead of printing them at least).

Answer (score 1):

Don't you mean:

```
for record in fetch_record:
    for rec in cname:
        try:
            for gram in c_ngram:
                if x:
                    for value in self.keyword_material_info:
                        if y:
                            for item in self.keyword_bse_list:
                                if z:
                                    raise GetOutOfLoop
        except GetOutOfLoop:
            break
```

But when you think you have to resort to exceptions to get out of nested loops, I would suggest breaking the nested loops into a function and using `return` instead. Like this:

```
def process_record(record):
    for rec in cname:
        for gram in c_ngram:
            if x:
                for value in self.keyword_material_info:
                    if y:
                        for item in self.keyword_bse_list:
                            if z:
                                return

for record in fetch_record:
    process_record(record)
```

Comment: thanks a lot, this is pretty clear now, I guess break was creating confusion for me.

Comment: Thanks for 2nd approach too, but in that case probably I will face issue counting the value for each for loop. In function count variable will behave like local var and during each function call it will reinitiated. So I prefer without function approach

Comment: Then put those in a baton object that you pass to the function. It helps to get that local variable state into structured objects so that you can pass it around.

Comment: yeah okay. Sorry to say, but after removing breaks I have one issue when I checked results.

Comment: For any record r1, if any `gram` gram is present in `r1` then `filter_company_level` should be incremented only once. But here for each iteration of `gram` value being incremented. So for 20 records I got this result: `Total results :  20
Filter at keyword level :  7
Filter at material info :  97
Filter at company name :  270
`

Comment: ACtually filter at each level should be less then 20, because total records are 20